# Ant: target "install" does not exist in the project

Tags: java, build, ant

I have to build two modules of the project using Ant. I have two xml files which I should use to build: project.xml and integration.xml. I use following command to build them:

`ant install -f <filename>.xml`

But the building (or installing) process ends successfully only for file project.xml. When I try command mentioned above with the integration.xml I receive:

`Target "install" does not exist in the project "integration"`

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look through your project.xml file and there will be a line like this there:

```
<target name="install"...>
```

Which is missing in the integration.xml, so in order to run task with the name "install" you need to add it to your buildfile.
You can look up further info here:  https://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html
Or you can just run 
`ant -p ${your_buildfile_name}` to list all build targets in the build file.

Answer (score 1):

The *target* that you give to ant (*install* in your case) refers to a definition in the build file.

In other words: one of your XML files contains an install target, the other does not.

So the solution is that you compare the two files to understand their differences. Either you have to add an install target to the second XML file, or you might simply have to use a different target with that one.